# How to create a simple widget?

Tags: plugin-development, dashboard-widgets

I have limited knowledge of PHP but I would like to try and create a widget. Basically all it needs to do is provide some text and a link to the user profile page as you can't route directly to that page on login. Would someone be able to point me in the write direction please. I have in my `grWidget.php` file:

```php
<?php

namespace Craft;

class GrWidget extends BasePlugin
{
  function getName()
    {
      return Craft::t('Gareth Widget');
    }

    function getVersion()
    {
      return '1.0';
    }

    function getDeveloper()
    {
      return 'Gareth Redfern';
    }

    function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
      return 'http://garethredfern.com';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are mixing up your [Primary Plugin Class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up) with your [Dashboard Widget](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/widgets).

**Plugin Structure:**

Assuming your plugin is called `Gareth` and your widget `Gr`, this files should be in your `/craft/plugins/gareth/` directory:

- `GarethPlugin.php`
- `templates/`

  - `GrWidget.html`
- `widgets/`

  - `Gareth_GrWidget.php`

---

**[Primary Plugin Class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up): `GarethPlugin.php`**

> Your primary plugin class defines all of the things that Craft needs
>   to know about your plugin, such as the plugin’s name, version number,
>   developer’s name and URL, and Global Settings.

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class GarethPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    function getName()
    {
         return Craft::t('Gareth');
    }

    function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0';
    }

    function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Gareth Redfern';
    }

    function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'http://garethredfern.com';
    }
}
```

---

**[Widget Class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/widgets): `Gareth_GrWidget.php`**

This class defines the widget types name `getName()` and its content `getBodyHtml()`.

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Gareth_GrWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Gr');
    }

    public function getBodyHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('gareth/GrWidget');
    }
}
```

---

**[Widget Template](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates): `GrWidget.html`**

```twig
This is just some text which will be shown inside the GrWidget.
<a href="{{ url('myaccount') }}">A link to my user profile</a>
```

---

**Result:**

[image: How the example Widget will look like]

---

**More:**

Check out the [Widget documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/widgets). Also take a look at Craft's default widgets which can be found in the `craft/app/widgets` directory.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Victor. You are right I wasn't really sure where to start but you have put me on the right path now. I hadn't seen the widget docs either so my bad there.

Comment: That is useful, the super simple happy brad widget also helped a lot https://github.com/mattstauffer/happybrad