# 'An unknown error occurred.' when trying to add new custom widget

Tags: plugin-development, error-message

I am hoping that somebody can help with this issue.

I followed [this excellent tutorial](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/how-to-create-a-simple-widget) on creating a custom widget in Craft. On completion, I uploaded the plugin to the `/craft/plugins/` directory, visited the page at `/admin/settings/plugins` and installed the plugin. All fine so far. Then, on returning to the dashboard, I clicked on New Widget, and selected the name of the widget. Following this, a message flashed up saying 'An unknown error occurred.' and little else happened.

It's probably user error, but if you could point out what I might have done incorrectly, that'd be useful.

**My Plugin Structure**

The plugin's called `Adlister` and the widget's called `Alu`, so in `/craft/plugins/adlister/` I have two folders ( `templates/` and `widgets/` ), and a file: `AdListerPlugin.php`. Within `templates/` is a file: `AluWidget.html` and within `widgets/` is `AdLister_AluWidget.php`.

**File Contents**

***AdListerPlugin.php***

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class AdListerPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    function getName()
    {
         return Craft::t('AdLister');
    }

    function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0';
    }

    function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Mark Syred';
    }

    function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'http://www.sypo.uk';
    }
}
```

***AluWidget.html***

```
<p>Click to perform <a href="http://example.co.uk/adlister-update.php?numDays=1">a daily update</a>.</p>
<p>Click to perform <a href="http://example.co.uk/adlister-update.php?numDays=3">an update on a Monday</a>.</p>
<p>Click to perform <a href="http://example.co.uk/adlister-update.php?numDays=7">a weekly update</a>.</p>
<p>Click to perform <a href="http://example.co.uk/adlister-update.php?numDays=30">a monthly update</a>.</p>
```

***AdLister_AluWidget.php***

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Adlister_AluWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Adlister Update');
    }

    public function getBodyHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('adlister/AluWidget');
    }
}
```

Any help that anyone could provide would be much appreciated.

With kind regards,

Mark

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this has any bearing, but the version of Craft I'm running is 2.6.2911.

Comment: I actually set up your plugin by using the code in your question, and adding the widget worked fine on my end. Are these stubs – i.e. anything else in your code besides the stuff you posted? Or is this the complete thing?

Comment: Also, did you check your log files under `/craft/storage/runtime/logs` (search for `[error]` and possibly your server error log files as well – might be a clue in there.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Thanks for your comment. The code in my question displays the complete code. It's good to know it works for someone! I will go ahead now and check the error logs...

Comment: Yeah, I set it up exactly like you describe, so without being able to reproduce the issue it's hard to advise. Hopefully there's a more helpful error message in the logs :)

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff I've checked the error logs - both on craft and in the server - and there's nothing relevant that I can see. I've resorted to contacting Pixel & Tonic via the Dashboard in Craft. Thanks anyway for your support.

Comment: Also check the network and console tabs in your browser's dev tools when you attempt to create the widget. Might be a JS error or something else you can spot there.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Thanks for pointing that out. I get: `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.singletrack-distribution.co.uk/index.php/admin/actions/dashboard/createWidget"` as an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel quite embarrassed, but I have finally got this thing working. The error that I had made was within `AdLister_AluWidget.php`. I had written at line 4: `class Adlister_AluWidget extends BaseWidget` instead of what it should have been: `class AdLister_AluWidget extends BaseWidget`. So, AdLister should have been written with an UPPER-CASE 'L' and not lower-case. If anyone else is struggling, hopefully my error will help them.

The correct code in full:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class AdLister_AluWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Adlister Update');
    }

    public function getBodyHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('adlister/AluWidget');
    }
}
```